# Getting highest value node using XPath

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

In XPath, how can I get the node with the highest value? e.g.

```
<tr>
   <td>$12.00</td>
   <td>$24.00</td>
   <td>$13.00</td>
</tr>
```

would return $24.00.

I'm using PHP DOM, so this would be XPath version 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spend the last little while trying to come up with the most elegant solution for you. As you know, `max` ins't available in XPath 1.0. I've tried several different approach, most of which don't seem very efficient.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXml('<table><tr><td>$12.00</td><td>$24.00</td><td>$13.00</td></tr></table>');

function dom_xpath_max($this, $nodes)
{
  usort($nodes, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strcmp($b->textContent, $a->textContent);'));

  return $this[0]->textContent == $nodes[0]->textContent;
}

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('php', 'http://php.net/xpath');
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions('dom_xpath_max');

$result = $xpath->evaluate('//table/tr/td[php:function("dom_xpath_max", ., ../td)]');

echo $result->item(0)->textContent;

?>
```

Alternatively, you could use a `foreach` loop to iterate through the result of a simpler XPath expression (once which only selects all of the TD elements) and find the highest number.

```
<?php

...

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $xpath->evaluate('//table/tr/td');

$highest = '';

foreach ( $result as $node )
  if ( $node->textContent > $highest )
    $highest = $node->textContent;

echo $highest;

?>
```

You could also use the XSLTProcessor class and a XSL document that uses the math:max function from [exslt.org](http://www.exslt.org/math/functions/max/index.html) but I've tried that and couldn't get it to work quite right because of the dollar signs ($).

I've tested both solutions and they worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it would be extremely difficult or not possible to write a single XPath query to return highest value which contains characters other than numbers like in your case `$`. But if you consider XML fragment excluding `$` like

```
<tr>
   <td>12.00</td>
   <td>24.00</td>
   <td>13.00</td>
</tr>
```

then you can write a single XPath query to retrieve the highest value node. 
`//tr/td[not(preceding-sibling::td/text() > text() or following-sibling::td/text() > text())]`

This query returns you `<td>` with value `24.00`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @babonk - This solution will **not** work with dollar signs. I've posted an answer with a 2 solutions that work with the dollar signs.

Comment: @Francois. Thats correct. This won't work with `$` sign. My answer was intended towards providing a single XPath query. Otherwise there are traditional ways (looping/recursion) of accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 1):

A pure XPath 1.0 solution is difficult: at the XSLT level you would use recursion, but that involves writing functions or templates, so it rules out pure XPath. In PHP, I would simply pull all the data back into the host language and compute the max() using PHP code.

Comment: Ok, so you'd suggest looping through the DomNodeList to build a values array then running max()?

Comment: @babonk - There's no need to create another array. Have a look at my second solution.